# Dict key with backslash

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Need to bring a backslash into a dictionary key name.
I have to use it as body in a REST API Post call

What I already tried:

```
r"\"
\\\\
"\\"
```

It never looks how expected.

How it should look: referring to the part `\"value\"`

```
{
    "packet": {
        "payload_encoding": "json",
        "payload": "{\"value\": 42}",
         "transceived_at": "2017-07-31T12:15:18.289981Z", 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the api really need the payload key to be set as \"value\": 42 or just "value":42? Since, in json you can't use single quotes, and to specify that a parameter (value in this case) needs to be enclosed in double-quotes, you have to escape the double quotes with \". There wouldn't have been any other way for them to write "value". When this json goes to the api, it will be interpreted as "value". If you want to just use "value", you could do "payload": '"value":42' and convert the dictionary into a jso, jsonified = json.dumps(thepayload)

Comment: you can convert the dictionary to json, I don't understand why do you want to add backslahes in dictionary keys

Comment: I finally found a way: See answer
Created a new dict with the values. and then add with json.dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way: See answer
Created a new dict with the values. and then add with json.dumps.

```
body = {}
body["packet"] = {}
body["packet"]["payload_encoding"] = "json"
body["packet"]["transceived_at"] = ReadingTime

UsableReadings = {}
UsableReadings["Value1"] = 42
UsableReadings["Value2"] = 420

body["packet"]["payload"] = json.dumps(UsableReadings)
body = json.dumps(body)
```